# Send HTTP Post with querystring in URL

Tags: java, android, http-post

I have doubts about send HTTP Post using querystring.

I have the follow code below but thie code not working. I try send by web service the user and password, embedded in URL, but it not working. this code cannot connect on web-service.

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String result = "";

            try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.11:8080/api/Usuario/doLogin?user="+user+"&senha="+password);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");               


                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }

                    result = response.toString();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("InputStream", e.getMessage());
                    }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: URL params are used in `GET` request.In `POST`request the values should be in the request body.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Check the connection between client and server. 192.168.0.11 is local network address...

Comment: but I'm using querystring, in query string we can send url it is possible to do it this way.

Comment: my web server is localhost, So, this ip-address is correct

Comment: do you know if me code is correct? if urlhttpconnection is correct?

Comment: You didn't say *what* is not working - does it throw an exception? Doesn't the client receive the values? ... ?

Comment: Also, it is generally not a very good idea to send passwords in query strings. I'd suggest sending them in the requests body which is how you're supposed to do it if you're using POST.

Comment: Mifeet do you have any example for me??

Comment: Miffet and Jeans, I'm usign post with querystring

Comment: in this form for example:   POST /map/route/45/waypoints?lat=35&long=74

Comment: but in this case I put user and password parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean GET request not POST,
and you should encode the variables in the query params, "user" and "password" in your case.

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.11:8080/api/Usuario/doLogin?user=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8")+"&senha="+ URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"));
```